# ways to arrange 6 men and 4 women in one line without 2 women next to each other (another solution?)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

One solution to the question was to arrange the 6 men which is $6!$ ways, then there's $7$ spaces to put each woman in between, so we multiply by ($\binom{7}{4}$), and their number of arrangements is just $4!$, which gives us the final answer: $6!\binom{7}{4}4!$ which is equal to $720 \cdot 35 \cdot 24=604,800$.

I'm trying to solve it the opposite way and got stuck, which is at first we arrange $4$ women which is $4!$ ways, then we have $5$ spaces to put 6 men in (there must be $2$ men that will be in one space), so what I tried to do is to look at $2$ men as one man, so I will have $5!$ ways to arrange them, but since I have two men that I counted as one man I multiplied $5! \cdot 2!$, and here I got stuck and I think I did something wrong. 
 
I would really appreciate any help, still new to the subject and trying to understand stuff deeper. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those are not the only cases. You can have $2$ men each in $3$ spaces between women or you can also put $3, 2, 1$ men in between. So it is going to be more cumbersome.

Comment: If you start with the women and try to insert the men, you have to necessarily have at least one man in each of the three spaces between.  Go ahead and take note of that in your mind.  Now, you have three more men and five available regions that you could place them in *with repeats allowed*.  Using the other form of stars-and-bars there are $\binom{3+5-1}{5-1}=\binom{7}{4}$ ways to do that.  Now that you've decided how many men stand between each woman or to the sides, you continue as before multiplying by $6!$ and $4!$ and arrive at the same expression for the answer.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much!

Comment: Formatting tip:  To obtain $\binom{n}{k}$, type `$\binom{n}{k}$`.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.